# Angular: File to import not found or unreadable: ~css-star-rating/scss/star-rating

Tags: angular, npm, sass

I'm trying to set up a project which is using Angular 6 in frontend. When I'm run the project using `ng serve` command there is an error as follows,

> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
>       Module build failed:
>       @import '~css-star-rating/scss/star-rating';
>       ^
>             File to import not found or unreadable: ~css-star-rating/scss/star-rating.
>             in D:\trackitRevamp\trackit3\src\main\Trackit-Revamp\src\styles.scss (line 10, column 1)

As the error says itself the error is in line 10 in `styles.scss` file,

```
@import '~css-star-rating/scss/star-rating';
```

Above is my line 10. What I want to know is how to resolve this error by installing this node module package?

But in my `package.json` I already have below node packages,

```
"angular-star-rating": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "css-star-rating": "^1.2.4",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the cause of the problem and hope this will helpfull for someone in the future, So what the actual cause is the version of `"angular-star-rating"` which I'm currently having is a mismatch with the version project expect. So I have to reinstall that or simply run following command to upgrade or downgrade version.

`$ npm install css-star-rating`

After running below command I can simply run `ng serve` to run the project and it will work.